# Redmine Omniauth Google plugin

Tags: google-oauth, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have installed Redmine Omniauth Google plugin and when I clicked "Login via Google" button, I got an error message:"You can not login using gmail.com domain." but I can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: provide a link to plugin

Answer (score 1):

You should add the domains you want to be able to login on the "Available domains" field. 
You can find this on plugin settings page.

It could be a list of domains like this:

```
google.com
yourdomain.com
yourotherdomain.com
```